# Create a Modal component that can be called by calling function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog

I'm trying to create a modal component like ant design that can be callable from outside of react node, like calling  `Modal()` in *actions.ts*.
the process of creating it most be something like that :
when we call `Modal()` it:

- creates a div element by id **modal-wrapper**
- append it to body
- render the `<ModalContainer />` to Dom using `ReactDOM.render( <ModalContainer/>, document.getElementById('modal-wrapper') )`
- remove the div element after modal has been closed.
  but I don't know how to implement it correctly . or this is even possible?
  if you have any other recommendation I would love to hear it

Comment: You can simply achieve this using `React.createProtal` api. Start reading from here=> https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html